# Анимированная обводка css как псевдоэлемент

Tags: html, css, анимация, transition

На сайте необходимо сделать анимацию при наведении на товар, чтобы `border` при наведении шел по кругу. Я выполнил это с использованием псевдоэлементов `:after` и `:before`.
Но теперь из-за этого нельзя кликнуть на страницу с товаром. Как сделать чтобы осталось анимация, и товары были бы кликабельны?

[Ссылка](http://niastar.ru/)

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/186999)

Comment: Нельзя кликнуть, так как у тебя псевдо элемент сверху...  Убери его назад.. Задай ему (псевдо элементу) `z-index: - 1 ;`

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY

```
//Colors
$background: #fefefe;
$text: #4b507a;

$cyan: #60daaa;
$yellow: #fbca67;
$orange: #ff8a30;
$red: #f45e61;
$purple: #6477b9;
$blue: #0eb7da;

// Basic styles
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;

  // Using inset box-shadow instead of border for sizing simplicity
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px $red;
  color: $red;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;

  // Required, since we're setting absolute on pseudo-elements
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.draw {
    transition: color 0.25s;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    // Set border to invisible, so we don't see a 4px border on a 0x0 element before the transition starts
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  // This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down)
  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  // And this the bottom & left borders (expands left, then up)
  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: $cyan;
  }

  // Hover styles
  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: $cyan; // Make borders visible
    border-right-color: $cyan;
    transition:
      width 0.25s ease-out, // Width expands first
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; // And then height
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: $cyan; // Make borders visible
    border-left-color: $cyan;
    transition:
      border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, // Wait for ::before to finish before showing border
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, // And then exanding width
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s; // And finally height
  }
}

// Inherits from .draw
.meet {

  &:hover {
    color: $yellow;
  }

  // Start ::after in same position as ::before
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  // Change colors
  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: $yellow;
    border-right-color: $yellow;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: $yellow;
    border-left-color: $yellow;
    transition: // Animate height first, then width
      height 0.25s ease-out,
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
  }

}

// Does not inherit
.center {
  &:hover {
    color: $purple;
  }

  // Set up base styles, we're going to scale instead of animating width/height
  &::before,
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform-origin: center; // Ensure scaling is done from the center (expands outwards)
  }

  // scale3d(<scale-horizontal>, <scale-vertical>, <scale-depth>);
  &::before {
    border-top: 2px solid $purple;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $purple;
    transform: scale3d(0,1,1); // Shrink only width
  }

  &::after {
    border-left: 2px solid $purple;
    border-right: 2px solid $purple;
    transform: scale3d(1,0,1); // Shrink only height
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1); // Show full-size
    transition: transform 0.5s;
  }
}

// Border spins around element
// ::before holds three borders that appear separately, one at a time
// ::after holds one border that spins around to cover ::before's borders, making their appearance seem smooth

.spin {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 0;

  &:hover {
    color: $blue;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  &::before {
    border: 2px solid transparent; // We're animating border-color again
  }

  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: $blue; // Show borders
    border-right-color: $blue;
    border-bottom-color: $blue;

    transition:
      border-top-color 0.15s linear, // Stagger border appearances
      border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.10s,
      border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.20s;
  }

  &::after {
    border: 0 solid transparent; // Makes border thinner at the edges? I forgot what I was doing
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-top: 2px solid $blue; // Shows border
    border-left-width: 2px; // Solid edges, invisible borders
    border-right-width: 2px; // Solid edges, invisible borders
    transform: rotate(270deg); // Rotate around circle
    transition:
      transform 0.4s linear 0s,
      border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s; // Solid edge post-rotation
  }
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}

.thick {
  color: $red;

  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  &::before {
    border: 2.5em solid transparent;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &::after {
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    background: $red;
    border-top-color: $red;
    border-right-color: $red;
    border-bottom-color: $red;
    transition:
      background 0s linear 0.4s,
      border-top-color 0.15s linear,
      border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.15s,
      border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.25s;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-top: 2.5em solid $red;
    border-left-width: 2.5em;
    border-right-width: 2.5em;
  }
}

/* Page styling */

html {
  background: $background;
}

body {
  background: $background;
  color: $text;
  font: 300 24px/1.5 Lato, sans-serif;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 36em;
  padding: 1em 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  isolation: isolate;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

Думаю, вам должно подойти.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ
Но это немного не то, снова пропадает кликабельность на псевдоэлементах

Comment: Тогда заверните весь ваш блок в ссылку

Comment: на многих страницах придется менять код html, если можно обойтись без этого, то было бы замечательно

Answer (score 0):

Было решено способом наложением слоями:
Для каждого псевдоэлемента добавлен `z-index:10` и `position: relative`, а для картинок, текста, цены и тд добавлен `z-index:15`

Answer (score 0):

вариант:

```css
.btn__submit {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

[type="submit"] {
    margin: 27px 0 0 0;
    font-family: "futura-demic-reg", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 9px 0;
    max-width: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
  
  cursor:pointer;
}

.line__wrap span {
  display: block;
  background: #ffb400;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(1){ 
  width: 0%; height: 2px; top: 0; left: 0;  
  animation: lineWidth .25s ease-in-out both paused;
}
.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(2){ 
  width: 2px; height: 0%; top: 0; right: 0;
  animation: lineHeight .25s .25s ease-in-out both paused;
}
.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(3){ 
  width: 0%; height: 2px; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
  animation: lineWidth .25s .5s ease-in-out both paused;
}
.line__wrap span:nth-of-type(4){ 
  width: 2px; height: 0%; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  animation: lineHeight .25s .75s ease-in-out both paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
   @-moz-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
     @-o-keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }   
        @keyframes lineWidth { to { width: 100%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }
   @-moz-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }
     @-o-keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }   
        @keyframes lineHeight { to { height: 100%; } }

.btn__submit:hover .line__wrap span {
 -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
      -o-animation-play-state: running;
         animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn__submit">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Отправить</button>

  <div class="line__wrap">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```